# Redirect affecting development folder

Tags: redirect

We're switching the theme on our site to one that's more mobile-first but I'm having some issues with the redirect.
Our current site settings have the wordpress address (URL) as: https://wnyskydiving.com/wordpress  and the site address (URL) as: https://wnyskydiving.com/
which works fine.

We set up our web.config file to redirect everything to the https site:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.web>
    <trust level="Full" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <!-- Set the default document -->
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <remove value="index.php" />
        <add value="index.php" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="false" />
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
            <rule name="WordPress: http://wnyskydiving.com/" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                <match url="*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                <action type="Rewrite" url="index.php" />
            </rule>
                <rule name="Redirect to https" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url=".*" />
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="false" />
                </rule></rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

The problem is...I set up our development site in a 'test2' folder and it works fine for the home page:
https://wnyskydiving.com/test2/
But, as soon as I try to use the menu or navigate to a full path URL on the dev site, it redirects me to the live site and I can't see my dev pages to be able to work on them.
https://wnyskydiving.com/test2/tandem-skydiving/
redirects to:
https://wnyskydiving.com/tandem-skydiving/

How do I get around this??
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I take it both installs are using the same database?

Comment: I've actually got the dev site using a different database so that any changes I make aren't reflected on the live site. I started with a copy of the live database but it is using a different database entirely.

Comment: Did you do a search replace for the URL?

Comment: Would I do that in the database? It seems like it's a redirect issue on the site since I can enter the complete URL and it dynamically changes it in the browser to go to the live site.

Comment: Yes, if your HTAccess redirected, then WP would redirect back and you'd end up in a neverending loop anyway. Don't rely on HTAccess to do rewriting, WP has its own system, the HTAccess rules it adds to begin with are just to pass all URLs to `index.php`. Likewise with Nginx or IIS ( it looks like you're using IIS or some other less common server )